# Right way to cancel Asynctask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is this the right way to cancel a `AsyncTask`?

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            RequestTask requestTask = new RequestTask();
            requestTask.execute();
            while(requestTask.isCancelled()) {
                if (requestTask.isCancelled())
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I used a `if` inside a `while` loop. I don't really know if the statements are right in there.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String[] kx_var_array = new String[10];
        String returnString = "";
        final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        final String deviceId, deviceSerial, deviceAndroidId;

        deviceId = "" + telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        deviceSerial = "" + telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();
        deviceAndroidId = "" + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        while (!isCancelled()){
        if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //email und passwort aus den Feldern in Variablen speichern
            String URLEmail = email.getText().toString().replace(" ", "");
            String URLPassword = password.getText().toString();

            if (URLEmail.length() > 128) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Email-Adresse ist zu Lang!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;
            } else if (URLPassword.length() > 64) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Passwort ist zu Lang!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;
            }


            //Response vom Server
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
            //HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
            //Empfange Daten
            //returnString = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            returnString = null;
            if (returnString == null) {
                cancel(true);
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return returnString;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();
    if (result != null) setKx_map(result);
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Laden fehlgeschlagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
```

For test of purposes I set `returnString == null`.
I want to be sure if I don't get anything back from Server, the `AsyncTask` stops without using more time and resources.

Comment: why you are cancelling the task when its about to finish almost?

Comment: because when i cancel it, the onPostExecute won't be executed.

Comment: why dont you are checking at post execute? `if(result==null){return;}`

Comment: you can cancel it from the main thread. `requestTask.cancel(true);` and override the method onCancelled of asynctask if you want to do anything special on cancelling the task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors with the above snippet:

- First, don't access `email` or `password` from within `doInBackground` - that executes on a separate thread and can create race conditions. Fetch the values from the views before creating the `AsyncTask`, and then pass them in as parameters.
- Second, why are you looping? Your snippet appears to repeatedly, and infinitely, send the email and password to the server until it receives a null response.
- Third, in your first snippet, the `while` loop will never actually execute: `requestTask.isCancelled()` won't be true until something calls `cancel()` on `requestTask`.

It *looks* to me like in your first snippet, you're trying to wait until the `AsyncTask` has completed processing, and then print a message if it fails. That won't work, and shouldn't be made to work, because it defeats the point of `AsyncTask`: to perform some task without blocking execution of the rest of the code. By the time your `AsyncTask` has even *started* executing, those last few lines of code in your first snippet will be a distant memory in that thread's execution. If printing an error message is what you want and using `cancel()` is how you want to signal the condition, override `onCancelled` in your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Yes that's what I want. I just want to print an error message for the User.

Comment: What you can do, then, is avoid all the loops and simply use your `if (returnString == null)` check to determine whether or not to cancel the task. However, using `cancel()` for that purpose, at that point in the code, is pretty overkill. What you could do instead is simply pass the null `returnString` along to `onPostExecute`, and handle the error condition checking (and message printing) there, alongside your success condition.

Comment: This is pretty easier than my way for printing error messages!! Thank you for your answer! That means using cancel(true) in doInBackground is totally wrong?

Comment: Not necessarily *wrong* - if you call `cancel(true)` inside `doInBackground()`, all it will do is cause `onCancelled()` to be called instead of `onPostExecute()`. There is some extra overhead to the `cancel` call, however, which is why I'd just skip it entirely and do the check in `onPostExecute`.

`cancel` is more aimed at something external to the `AsyncTask` telling it "I no longer care about the work you're doing", instead of the task itself halting with an error.

Comment: YES!!! I throw the cancel(true) in doInBackground out ant checked if it's null in the onPostExecute and now it works!!! Thank you!!